# ntdll.dll error running c# service on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: ntdll

I have a problem with a customer. I have a service who down once or twice per month. 
Windows Event viewer has an error :

*Nom de l’application défaillante MaintiMediaServeurService.exe, version : 3.8.600.21236, horodatage : 0x509a3c59
Nom du module défaillant : ntdll.dll, version : 6.1.7601.17514, horodatage : 0x4ce7c8f9
Code d’exception : 0xc0000374
Décalage d’erreur : 0x00000000000c40f2
ID du processus défaillant : 0x5b0
Heure de début de l’application défaillante : 0x01ce680c6ab54f85
Chemin d’accès de l’application défaillante : C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\MaintiMediaServeurService.exe
Chemin d’accès du module défaillant: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
ID de rapport : 2b6bea7b-d403-11e2-981c-00505683000f*

I try to use Windlg to have more information an I have this :

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 AMD64

Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



*** wait with pending attach

Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***

****************************************************************************

* Symbol loading may be unreliable without a symbol search path.           *

* Use .symfix to have the debugger choose a symbol path.                   *

* After setting your symbol path, use .reload to refresh symbol locations. *

****************************************************************************

Executable search path is:

ModLoad: 00000000`10190000 00000000`1019a000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\MaintiMediaServeurService.exe

ModLoad: 00000000`773f0000 00000000`77599000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fa1e0000 000007fe`fa24f000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL

ModLoad: 00000000`772d0000 00000000`773ef000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd410000 000007fe`fd47c000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fee00000 000007fe`feedb000   C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`ff4d0000 000007fe`ff56f000   C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`ff4b0000 000007fe`ff4cf000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd710000 000007fe`fd83d000   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`f7f80000 000007fe`f8019000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`ff060000 000007fe`ff0d1000   C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`ff570000 000007fe`ff5d7000   C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`771d0000 00000000`772ca000   C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`ff6f0000 000007fe`ff6fe000   C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd840000 000007fe`fd909000   C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`ff400000 000007fe`ff42e000   C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL

ModLoad: 000007fe`ff5e0000 000007fe`ff6e9000   C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`f6d90000 000007fe`f772d000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`74e80000 00000000`74f49000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_88df89932faf0bf6\MSVCR80.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fddc0000 000007fe`feb48000   C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`febf0000 000007fe`fedf3000   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd300000 000007fe`fd30f000   C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`ee730000 000007fe`ef60c000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\mscorlib\8f7abb6f7384aad8fc43659820726eab\mscorlib.ni.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd230000 000007fe`fd23f000   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`ecf00000 000007fe`ed925000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System\3e6eefab37b44e147db80a3c34f0ac05\System.ni.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`f7f30000 000007fe`f7f7c000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.ServiceProce#\d69463a51d3536074bff664c0a097b1f\System.ServiceProcess.ni.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`f7da0000 000007fe`f7f24000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`f7b60000 000007fe`f7d97000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Drawing\ad884485b63f08acfaf791d2dfaadd32\System.Drawing.ni.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`ea480000 000007fe`eb516000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Windows.Forms\0737590c91350bf9ce7416cbbf789bc7\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`74e60000 00000000`74e70000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\MaintiServeur.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`f7a10000 000007fe`f7b53000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Configuration\df2bfb30ffdbfbb49d2c5ef6fc763578\System.Configuration.ni.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`f5f50000 000007fe`f65f5000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Xml\318b11a6b944c9ef2998d374c9d5bda8\System.Xml.ni.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`74e30000 00000000`74e3c000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\servSession.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`74970000 00000000`74b3a000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\MaintiServManagerDal.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`74e20000 00000000`74e2c000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\Licence.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`74e10000 00000000`74e1c000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\Licences.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fcbd0000 000007fe`fcbe7000   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fc8d0000 000007fe`fc917000   C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd2e0000 000007fe`fd2f4000   C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd1d0000 000007fe`fd227000   C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`10000000 00000000`1001c000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\win64\sglw.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`feee0000 000007fe`fef2d000   C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fdaf0000 000007fe`fdaf8000   C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fb7c0000 000007fe`fb7cb000   C:\Windows\system32\HID.DLL

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd910000 000007fe`fdae7000   C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.DLL

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd4c0000 000007fe`fd4f6000   C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`ff0e0000 000007fe`ff1b7000   C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd3f0000 000007fe`fd40a000   C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd480000 000007fe`fd4ba000   C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd500000 000007fe`fd667000   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd3e0000 000007fe`fd3ef000   C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`ebd70000 000007fe`ec5bb000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Data\d71dfde5e15e6b4271c9ce4c514775b2\System.Data.ni.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`02840000 00000000`02b3f000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`74e00000 00000000`74e08000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\servGenericADO.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`f7920000 000007fe`f7a05000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Transactions\5fbe4fcbb4259d38e57006802c957e23\System.Transactions.ni.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`01e50000 00000000`01e99000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`f7810000 000007fe`f791d000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.EnterpriseSe#\1f84610e9a8c80e23e82f82cc4a894a3\System.EnterpriseServices.ni.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`74300000 00000000`74303000   C:\Windows\system32\security.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fce80000 000007fe`fce8b000   C:\Windows\system32\SECUR32.DLL

ModLoad: 000007fe`fd1a0000 000007fe`fd1c5000   C:\Windows\system32\SSPICLI.DLL

ModLoad: 000007fe`fc7c0000 000007fe`fc7ca000   C:\Windows\system32\credssp.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fc960000 000007fe`fc9b7000   C:\Windows\system32\schannel.DLL

ModLoad: 00000000`48060000 00000000`4806d000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\instapi.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fcd50000 000007fe`fcd9e000   C:\Windows\system32\ncrypt.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fcd20000 000007fe`fcd42000   C:\Windows\system32\bcrypt.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fc810000 000007fe`fc85c000   C:\Windows\system32\bcryptprimitives.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`74070000 00000000`7417a000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\MaintiServControllerBll.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`f6c90000 000007fe`f6d8d000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Runtime.Remo#\caddda432d02308c325519a8e2f09dc4\System.Runtime.Remoting.ni.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`74d00000 00000000`74db2000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\MaintiControllerObject.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`71780000 00000000`7295e000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\MaintiServImpression.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`74cf0000 00000000`74d00000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\MaintiImpressionObject.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fcb70000 000007fe`fcbc5000   C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fc550000 000007fe`fc557000   C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fcb60000 000007fe`fcb67000   C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fbcd0000 000007fe`fbce5000   C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`f5de0000 000007fe`f5df5000   C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fc9f0000 000007fe`fca4b000   C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`f5dd0000 000007fe`f5ddb000   C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fb540000 000007fe`fb567000   C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL

ModLoad: 000007fe`fb500000 000007fe`fb50b000   C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL

ModLoad: 000007fe`fa360000 000007fe`fa368000   C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll

ModLoad: 000007fe`fb430000 000007fe`fb483000   C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`74ce0000 00000000`74ce8000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\Tribofilm.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`74cd0000 00000000`74cde000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceProcess.resources\2.0.0.0_fr_b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.ServiceProcess.resources.dll

(f44.47c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll -

ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:

00000000`77440530 cc              int     3

0:012> g

ModLoad: 000007fe`f96c0000 000007fe`f98cd000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.VisualBas#\4b85c3384fdda12490074283615d4723\Microsoft.VisualBasic.ni.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`01ea0000 00000000`01ebc000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\win64\sglw.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`01ca0000 00000000`01cbc000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\win64\sglw.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`01ca0000 00000000`01cbc000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\win64\sglw.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`01ca0000 00000000`01cbc000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\win64\sglw.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`01ca0000 00000000`01cbc000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\win64\sglw.dll

ModLoad: 00000000`01cc0000 00000000`01cdc000   C:\Program Files (x86)\TRIBOFILM Industries\MaintiMedia Serveur Service\win64\sglw.dll

Critical error detected c0000374

(f44.bc4): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)

ntdll!RtlUnhandledExceptionFilter+0x29f:

00000000`774b40bf cc              int     3
```

EDIT : I try to have a best execption catching but the error message is always the same.
Here is my service code:

```
[MTAThread()]
public static void Main()
{
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun = null;

//  Plusieurs services NT s'excutent dans le mme processus. Pour ajouter
//  un autre service  ce processus, modifiez la ligne suivante
//  pour crer un second objet service. Par exemple,
// 
//    ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase () {New Service1, New MySecondUserService}
// 
ServicesToRun = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { new MaintiMediaService() };

System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain().UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MaintiMediaService_UnhandledException);

System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}

static void MaintiMediaService_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
EventLog l = new EventLog();
l.Source = "Application";
if (e.ExceptionObject != null)
{
    Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
    l.WriteEntry(e.GetType().ToString() + " - " + ex.GetType().ToString() + " : " + ex.Message + " \r\n " + ex.StackTrace.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
}
else
    l.WriteEntry(e.GetType().ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
throw new NotImplementedException();        
}
```

Have you any Idee?

Comment: It has nothing to do with ntdll, I will give 99.9% warranty - there is some bug in your application, so try to get more debug info (some stack backtrace at least)

Comment: Someone has another Idee?